# Odd problem with UIView touch handling

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, ios

For my iPad app, I'm using a `UIViewController` subclass called `SidebarViewController` to display some stuff in a sidebar. In the sidebar I have a calendar control. I'm using the open source Kal component from http://github.com/klazuka/Kal. In the `-viewDidLoad` method of `SidebarViewController`, I'm creating a new instance of `KalView` (the main view for the calendar) and adding it as a subview of `SidebarViewController`'s view:

```
_logic = [[KalLogic alloc] initForDate:[NSDate date]];
_calendarView = [[KalView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 62.0, 273.0, 239.0) delegate:self logic:_logic];
KalDate *currentDate = [KalDate dateFromNSDate:[NSDate date]];
[_calendarView selectDate:currentDate];
[self.view insertSubview:_calendarView atIndex:0];
```

The calendar displays and everything, but there's one problem. The main component of the calendar is the `KalGridView`, which is a subview of `KalView`. It displays the date tiles, etc. When the app starts, for some reason, the `KalGridView` does not receive touches. The touches are intercepted by `SidebarViewController`'s view. Weirdly enough, if I tap the month change buttons at the top of the calendar to change the month, the `KalGridView` starts receiving touches again.

I can't figure out why this is happening, because none of the other subviews of `SidebarViewController` are affected by the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the KalView in the XIB instead of creating it in code seemed to solve the problem. This definitely looks like a bug, but I don't know the circumstances under which it can be reproduced so I don't think I can file it.

Comment: Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011579/add-a-child-view-controllers-view-to-a-subview-of-the-parent-view-controller