# How to add UITableView inside custom UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

I want to create common custom view with uitableview. I can do it using view controller and add subview as follows.

```
ViewController *vwCon=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
vwCon.view.center=self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:vwCon.view];
```

But after scrolling table view app become crash. So how can I add uitableview inside custom UIView?

Comment: see this link may be hepls you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737426/how-to-insert-the-uitextview-into-uialertview-in-ios

Comment: What is the error message you are getting when the app crashed. Please provide that Error Message also.

Comment: I think you're adding a child view controller without telling to the parent view controller. Take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011579/add-a-child-view-controllers-view-to-a-subview-of-the-parent-view-controller

Comment: what is error messages.. we can get conclustion

Comment: show us the code of how you added tableview and what is the crash log

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add a view controller as a subview - in fact Im not sure whether you are allowed to at all.  You need to present a view controller modally, or push it as part of a navigation controller.  I doubt you really want that though- instead just use a UIView here rather than a view controller. Then you can add that as a subview to another view.

You also mention tableviews though.  Have you looked at the storyboard?  Its easiest to do all that in there - just drag a UITableview object from the objects list on the right hand side, into the main view controller.